# How to make api call in react function based view

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react'

componentDidMount(){
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.com/users/`)
    .then(res => res.hson())
    .then(res => {
        .console.log(res)
    })
}

const App  = () => {
    return (
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    )
}

export default App;
```

How to make api call in react function based view.

Here it is saying componentDidMount not found.

Is there any way to make api call using function based view.

Please have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React 16.8 has [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) Hook.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react';
const App  = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState('');
    useEffect(() => {
      fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.com/users/`)
      .then(res => res.hson())
      .then(res => {
       setData(res);
      })
    });
    return (
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Where i can store the res?

Comment: Can you please edit?

Comment: @soubhagyapradhan updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

componentDidMount should be inside class component.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'


class App extends Component  {

    componentDidMount(){
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.com/users/`)
    .then(res => res.hson())
    .then(res => {
        .console.log(res)
    })


    render() {
    return (
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    )
}

}

export default App;
```

Comment: Is there any way to make api call without class?

Comment: React 16.8 onwards -> useEffects(); This will do same thing but in functional component like yours.

Comment: Thanks anil. In useEffects can i store api in state?

Comment: Where i can store api res?

Comment: yes you can store state in useState() Hook.